# MySQL select from char column using int - leading zero causes unexpected result

Tags: php, mysql, pear

I have the following data:

```
stockcode (CHAR) | description (VARCHAR)
----------------------------------------------
1234               | some product
01234              | some other product
```

I run the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE stockcode = " . $db->quoteSmart($stockcode)
$res = $db->query($sql);
```

If I pass the stock code "01234" in, I get the second row as expected. If I pass in "1234" I get both rows, when I expect to only get the first.

By echoing out the sql statements, it seems to be because only the 01234 stockcode gets quotes around it, the 1234 one doesn't (presumably quoteSmart thinks as it is an integer it doesn't need quoting?).

Mysql is then comparing the int 1234 to the CHAR column, and deciding they both match (presumably it is doing the comparison as ints?)

There are a lot of places in the code which build queries like this, and 99% of the time, the stockcode variable will be alphanumeric, it's only occasionaly entirely numeric, and very rarely contains a leading zero, this is just a fluke occurrence I stumbled across today.

Can anyone recomend an easy solution?

Comment: I think you need to put stockcode between single quotes: $sql = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE stockcode = '" . $db->quoteSmart($stockcode) . "';";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly casting your variables to strings:

```
$db->quoteSmart((string)$stockcode);
// instead of:
// $db->quoteSmart($stockcode);
```

**Edit:**

If this does not work, I imagine that `quoteSmart()` isn't really that smart (or it's trying to be too smart for it's own good), so you'll very likely need to stop using it and stick to bound parameters (which I suggest over this method anyway).

Comment: That's got it, thanks a lot. I just needed to be very explicit about types in a few key places.

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes so the char in the database don't get converted to numbers for the comparison

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM stock 
                  WHERE stockcode = '" . $db->quoteSmart($stockcode). "'"
```

2nd Version:

```
$stockcode_str = $db->quoteSmart($stockcode);
if (is_numeric($stockcode_str))
    $stockcode_str = "'$stockcode_str'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stock 
                      WHERE stockcode = $stockcode_str";
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is when quoteSmart DOES return quoted text (in the 99% of cases where stockcode is a string), I end up with double single quotes, and a mysql error.